# How to use translations in Django?

Tags: python, django, localization, translation, locale

I'm following the Django tutorials about translation, however I cannot make it work. I'm probably missing something so simple that they didn't bother to write, but I can't see what.

my settings.py has the following declarations :

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
_ = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
  ('en', 'English'),
  ('fr', 'French'),
)
LOCALE_PATHS= (
                os.path.join( SITE_ROOT, 'locale').replace('\\','/'),
               )
```

my view looks like this :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as __
#...
 def translation_test(request):
        output = __("Yes")
        return HttpResponse(output)
```

and my `ProjectRoot/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` file has this :

```
msgid "Yes"
msgstr "Oui"
```

So I expect my view to generate "Oui", however, it generates "Yes". What am I missing here?

**P.S.** I also tried with a template file, because I need this to work too:

my_template.html :

```
{% extends "base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
<a>{% trans "Yes" %}</a>
```

Again, no translation. What should I do to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And I want to add that I'm confused with the language setting in settings.py, because it should be user-specific, right? How do I get the setting from the database, and apply it to the translation. Why is there a `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'` constant? I just wanted to add this question to reflect my confusion here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

French should be the active language to see the translated value.

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference to see how django determines the active language.

You can test the translation to see if there's something wrong with your translation config by settings LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'